# Smooth shade zoom in issue

Tags: rendering, lighting, cloth-simulation

[image]

when I zoom in shade smooth works but when I zoom out it looks like flat shade activates again? it looks like it’s baking into the cloth sim and it’s being rendered as well.(on her legs)

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Unfortunately we cannot help you with so little details. Perhaps you can at least provide the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.